# How to get the name of the current property in .NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.reflection

I need to be able to access the name of the current property on a class in .NET Core.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _myProperty;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get => _myProperty;
        set
        {
            // GOAL: Check my property name and then do something with that information. 

            // The following used to works in the full .NET Framework but not .NET Core.
            // var propName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

            _myProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the full .NET Framework, we could just use reflection as below.

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

(We recall that a property is really just a method under the hood.)

However, it does not appear this functionality is available in .NET Core 1.1--although it (may/will) be available in .NET Standard 2.0.

On this GitHub issue (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12496), there is a reference to using `GetMethodInfoOf` to access the property name. However, I have been unable to locate any example of this method, and the GitHub link pointing to a possible example appears to be broken.

What other strategy or technique could one use to retrieve the name of the current property?

Many thanks!

Comment: What about nameof(MyProperty) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I am totally misunderstanding your issue here but what about simply using the [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) operator?

```
var propName = nameof(MyProperty);
```

Comment: I believe the challenge with this approach is that I would have to include the property in the nameOf function. I am not sure how to get a handle on the current property from within the property itself.

Comment: Exactly the way @mm8 said: `nameof(MyProperty)`. You don't need to get a handle on the property, this is a compile-time, language-level thing.